# VIM - in colorscheme file, how to have different colours depending on what the syntax is?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, file-types, syntax

I use VIM and I want I use my own customized slate colorscheme (slate-mine.vim). In slate-mine.vim, is there a way for me to do something like

```
if syntax == django html
    then apply the following commands:
        :hi PreProc guifg=red guibg=white ctermfg=red
        :hi String guifg=SkyBlue ctermfg=darkcyan
```

?

Comment: This is closely related to [your follow-up question](http://superuser.com/questions/700373/vim-how-to-change-color-of-if-else-endif-for-and-endfor-statements/700384#700384), and I've written an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; the `:highlight` commands from the colorscheme are **global**.

If you only edit one type of file in a Vim session, you can conditionally redefine the colors, e.g. in `~/.vim/after/syntax/htmldjango.vim`. If you're willing to spend some more effort, you can define `:autocmds` (e.g. on `WinEnter`) that toggle (search on Stack Overflow, there have been questions about that), but **you will never be able to see two contradicting highlight group settings at once**.

Note that this sort of redefinition should not be necessary, as individual syntax files *link* to the names defined by the colorscheme with individual names like e.g. `htmlTag` (links to `Function`), and you can change that link.