# VIM - How to change color of if, else, endif, for and endfor statements

Tags: vim, html, syntax-highlighting, django

I just Django html so I have the normal html tags as well as the if, else, endif, for and endfor statements. I use a customized version of the colorscheme called slate. There is a line in the colorscheme which says this:

```
:hi Statement guifg=CornflowerBlue ctermfg=lightblue
```

and it turns all html tags and if, else, endif, for and endfor statements to a cornflowerBlue color. How do I make the color of the if, else, endif, for and endfor statements a different color than the html tags?

Comment: Phew; you're bombarding us with many related questions. Please try to reflect and search for solutions first, and show what you've found and attempted next time!

Comment: @IngoKarkat whoops okay I will do that next time. I tried reading :help syntax but everything was going over my head so I decided to just post the questions here. But thanks for the help, solved all my problems regarding VIM.

Comment: Hey, I'm glad you've got it all sorted out now. Vim's learning curve is steep; you've just been through some complex stuff; now enjoy a truly powerful editor!

Comment: I hereby declare you king of the XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding highlight links are these:

from `syntax/django.vim`:

```
HiLink djangoStatement Statement
```

from `syntax/html.vim`:

```
HtmlHiLink htmlTagName                 htmlStatement
HtmlHiLink htmlStatement          Statement
```

You see that both end up linking to the `Statement` group defined in your colorscheme, and colored blue in your case.

To change those, pick highlight groups from your colorscheme (e.g. `Special` and `Constant`), and redefine the links in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
highlight link htmlTagName Special
highlight link djangoStatement Contant
```

The hidden magic of the `HiLink` command (which is just a wrapper for `:hi def link`) is that when a link exists (like with the above two lines), the `def`ault won't be activated.

Alternatively, you could also define new colors on the spot (but it's best centralized in a colorscheme):

```
highlight htmlTagName ctermfg=Cyan guifg=Cyan
```